# tbody not allowing click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, click

I wrote this up quickly because I am having problems with it.  I apologize if the code looks messy.  Is tbody not clickable?  There is no alert, and I don't see any obvious errors

relevant php

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo
'<tbody class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment"
        id = "reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment">
    <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["name"].
            '</td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentLocaton"
                            id="reserveAPickupAppointmentLocaton">'
                    .$row["location"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentSubLocaton"
                            id="reserveAPickupAppointmentSubLocaton">'
                    .$row["subLocation"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime"
                            id="reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime">'
                .$row["startTime"].
            '</span>    - 
            <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime"
                            id="reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime">'
            .$row["endTime"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentDate"
                            id="reserveAPickupAppointmentDate">'
                .$row["date"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

jquery included in my document ready functon

```
   $("#reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").click (function() {
    alert ("TEST");
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that your ID matches your class frightens be a bit. I don't know `php`, but it seems from the `while` that you're creating more than one `tbody` in a loop.

This means that you'd have more than one element with the ID `reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment`. If so it is invalid, and very likely that only the first one will be matched by the selector.

To answer your question directly, yes a `tbody` can have a handler` as long as you allow the event to bubble up to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/hEw54/

---

Not knowing the rest of your code, I'd guess that you want the ID on the table, and then to select all `tbody` elements below it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment tbody').click(function() {
        alert ("TEST");
    });
});
```

Or you could just select directly by class:

```
$(function() {
    $('.reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment').click(function() {
        alert ("TEST");
    });
});
```

---

*I updated the code above to be placed in a jQuery DOM ready handler. You'll notice that the two examples are slightly different. They're essentially identical, the second being a shortcut for the first. There are other minor differences, but nothing to be concerned with here.*

Also note that some people mistake the following for DOM ready code:

```
(function() {

    // I'm not a DOM ready construct

})();
```

Comment: but I want each tbody's clickable, then I will use JS to pull the text string out and insert it in my sql..most of the classes are just placeholders until I do the stylesheet, and likely the names will change.  I imagine it would work similarly to giving each button a class "button" and then doing a click from that, which is a pretty common action.

Comment: @radleybobins: Then place the ID on the `table`, and select it like this `$('#reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment tbody')`

Comment: @radleybobins: I updated my answer with this information, and also showing how to select by class. There are many ways to do this, but the main thing to take away from this is to never have duplicate IDs on a page.

Comment: changing the id to the table and then selecting differently did not work.  I will now try to pick it by class, but I think I tried that earlier and it did not work.  Is there any more of my code you would like to see?  There really is nothing else that is relevant.

Comment: @radleybobins: Then I'd guess that you're running the jQuery code before the DOM is ready. Probably at the top of the page? Either move the script to just inside the closing `</body>`, or run your code inside a DOM ready handler. I'll update my answer to add the DOM ready code.

Comment: ...oops, I see in your question that you're in DOM ready. I'll need to see more to know then. Could it be that you're mistaking `(function() { /*...*/ })()` for DOM ready code?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help so far.  That jsfiddle page was SUPER handy, thanks for posting that.  It is saying that my code worked fine once I removed the php from the table(even with matching id, class, and duplicate id).  So, I guess I'll take another look at the containing php.

Comment: okay, you are totally right, I am running the jquery before this table is produced.  I was loading it when the page loaded, but I should be able to stick it in right after my table instead now.  I'll keep working with it, but I'm pretty sure that is the problem, so i'll mark this as the answer

UPDATE: This worked after testing

Comment: @radleybobins: Alright, let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use onclick with a TABLE, TBODY or a TR, but you can attach it to the TD with the jQuery child selector